# How can I change prettier preferences in a nest.js project without getting style errors?

Tags: nestjs, eslint, prettier

I personally prefer to use double quotes over single quotes in all my projects. I recently began to migrate an express project over to using nest.js and it came with a .prettierrc file that contained

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all"
}
```

When I deleted the first line and I opened any file, I would get errors saying to change my double quotes back to single quotes. My .eslintrc file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: "tsconfig.json",
    sourceType: "module",
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"],
  extends: [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
  ],
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: [".eslintrc.js"],
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
  },
};
```

I tried to remove the prettier/recommended plugin but that removed *all* the prettier suggestions, not just the single/double quote one. I've looked up a lot of suggestions but was unable to find a single one that addressed this problem.

Is there a clean way to change these preferences or do I just have to live with single quotes?

As always, if you answer or attempt to answer this question, thank you for your time.

Comment: What if you explicitly put `"singleQuote": false`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe doesn't work /:

Comment: You may need to restart the eslint processing server after changing the prettier config. Does that help at all?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Restarting VSCode fixed this for me. 